# How to get a dictionary key when the value is a list of values in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to get the key that has a list of values. If a user input matches one of the values, the key gets returned.

```
 self.data_base = {
        knife[0].knife_name: knife[0].knife_uses,
        knife[1].knife_name: knife[1].knife_uses,
        knife[2].knife_name: knife[2].knife_uses,
        knife[3].knife_name: knife[3].knife_uses,
        knife[4].knife_name: knife[4].knife_uses,
        knife[5].knife_name: knife[5].knife_uses,
        knife[6].knife_name: knife[6].knife_uses,
        knife[7].knife_name: knife[7].knife_uses
    }
```

## knife_uses is a list of strings.

## if the user input matches one of the list of uses, the knife name gets returned.

Comment: your dictionary is the other way round. The key gives access to the value.

Comment: I suppose more knives can have a given input value. In that case, what name would you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return key directly by the value. Because many key can have same value. Instead you can loop through the dictionary and return the key of the first value which match with input. You can do it like this:

```
for key, value in self.data_base.items():
    if(user_input == value):
        return key
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to loop through the dictionary with

```
for k, v in self.data_base.items():
    # if input matches v, return k
```